# How to create link to go to shopping cart

Tags: magento, redirect, checkout, cart

I have the following href on a page /example/index.php that I want to take me to my magento shopping cart:

```
href="/example/catalog/index.php/checkout/cart/"
```

However, it always redirects to /example/catalog/

When I am on /example/catalog/ and I trigger the same href it goes to the correct page but not from my main page.

Can someone please explain how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Is your Magento installation inside `/example/catalog/`?

If yes, then you can

```
href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart') ?>"
```

Comment: Yes, Magento is installed inside /example/catalog/ but the href is coming from /example/. When I use the code you provide I get access forbidden. When I type the url above straight into the browser it goes but not when coming from the href